# connect my galaxy s duos phone as mass storage or drivers

Tags: drivers, usb, phone

i want the drivers of my phone to be installed in Ubuntu 12.04 Lts  please help me on this

Comment: you don't need to install drivers for your phone,just change media transfer mode to mass storage mode in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to install any extra driver for your Smartphone to use it as a mass storage device. I am also having Samsung galaxy duos and there is no problem like this. What you have to do is, simply connect your phone with laptop/desktop using data cable. It will automatically detect your phone. Ubuntu12.04LTS is preloaded with the necessary drivers.